# Obtaining an error while getting groups of an user from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to get AD user's groups. 
The **user** is situated in **hq.example.company.com/Deep/Users** where Deep and Users are organizational units. 
The **groups** are situated in **hq.example.company.com/Deep/Groups**.

Here is my code:

```
var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
    "hq.example.company.com", "dc=hq,dc=example,dc=company,dc=com");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, "user");
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetGroups();
foreach (var p in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", p.Name);
}
```

The "groups" variable contains "Domain users" group and some custom groups from hq.example.company.com/Deep/Groups.
"Domain users" group's name outputs without errors but other groups throw such error:
**"The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist"**.
Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds weird.  Try `DisplayName`, `DistinguishedName`, `Guid` or `Sid`.  Do you see similar error?

Comment: i've tried already - same error.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permission to read any attributes from the object

Comment: i'm running this code being logged in as administrator.